# How to integrate customer pole display in point of sale module of openerp

Tags: python, postgresql, openerp-7

How to integrate customer pole display in point of sale module of openerp?
can you tell me how to make connection in between openerp and customer pole display(for point of sale)

Your help will  be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the **PointOfSaleController** class located in

```
point_of_sale/controllers/main.py file
```

for customer pole display.